# What areas in EE overlap closely with CS

Tags: computer-networks, research

I am doing bachelors in Electronics & Communication Engg.. But most of my work happened to be in Web development.. I am thinking to do my bachelor thesis which very closely overlaps with my recent work.

Are there any specific areas in CS, EE (may be Computer Networking in broad terms) that I can take up?

Comment: Just a *wild* guess (being neither a CS nor an EE), but ECC design would involve information theory (CS) and EE knowledge of noise effects and the material (and design), power use, and latency costs of implementing particular encodings.

Comment: That depends on what you are interested in.. there are several research areas in CS that significantly overlap with ECE, that can be Signal Processing, Coding Theory, Information Theory. Also one interpretation of Pattern Recognition and Optimization is though the lens of ECE. These are just _some_ areas, there are many more! As you make your way into research, most of the areas (esp. in systems) will seem to converge in a way. 
Don't limit your choices, just because of your background, instead if you like a subject/area, just learn it for the sake of learning it. :)

Comment: what about networks (i.e. mobile,wireless networks)

Answer (score 4):

One very close overlap is of course Computer Architecture.

Another close overlap (which incidentally happens to be my speciality) is EDA (CAD for VLSI designers). EDA requires development of fairly sophisticated parallel algorithms for things such as routing, RC extraction, optical proximity correction, etc., as well as understanding of the underlying VLSI physics.

Other subjects include telecommunication and signal processing, as pointed out in Subhayan's comment.